# Django : After submitting form, the browse button disappears

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I am working on pdf data extraction project.there i am browse pdf file using django-forms filefield and then displaying extracted data on same page.everything works fine but the problem is after submitting browsed file, extracted data appear on same page but browse button get disappear.

forms.py

```
class browse(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()
```

views.py

```
def index(request):  
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        user = browse(request.POST, request.FILES)  
        if user.is_valid():  
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])#store file in upload folder
            path = "pdfextractor/static/upload/"+ str(request.FILES['file'])#path of selected file
            result = extract_data(path)#extract data from file
            context = {'result':result}
            return (render(request,'pdfextractor/index.html',context))
    else:  
        user = browse()  
        return render(request,"pdfextractor/index.html",{'form':user})
```

index.html

```
<body>  
    <form method="POST" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
            {% csrf_token %}  
            {{ form.as_p }}  

            <input type="Submit" name="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>

    {% for key, value in result.items %}
    <h1>{{key}} : {{value}}</h1>
    {% endfor %}
</body>
```

output

[image]

here you can see browse button disappear.now here i want that browse button so that user can browse new file directly from here
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `POST` part of the request, the form is not being populated through the `context` while in the else clause it is being done.

You can create a new form and add it to context:

```
context = {
    'result': result,
    'form': browse(),
}
```

But, do note that in template form is rendered above the results so it will push the result down in the page when visible.

Answer (score 1):

It's because your form is not included in your `if` statement so it becomes `None`.

```
def index(request):
    result = None
    form = None
    if request.method == 'POST':  
        form = browse(request.POST, request.FILES)  
        if form.is_valid():  
            handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file']) # store file in upload folder
            path = "pdfextractor/static/upload/"+ str(request.FILES['file'])#path of selected file
            result = extract_data(path) # extract data from file
    else:
        form = browse()
    context = {"form": form, "result": result}
    return render(request,'pdfextractor/index.html', context)
```